# What is use of Propagate Columns option in SAS Data Integration studio

Tags: sas

In SAS Data Integration Studio, under the 'Action' menu, there is an option to 'Propagate Columns'. What is the use of this?

Answer (score 0):

The reads the metadata on the input table and pushes the column definitions into the down stream nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To 'propagate columns' means to move columns from source to target or from target to source in the mapping. You can use action -> propogate only when you select a transformation in the job. then you can propagate columns from source to target for that sas di transformation.